# Working with differential forms

Tags: differential-geometry, coordinate-systems

The spherical to cartesian transformations are usually given in by the relation of coordinates, lets consider only the coordinate $x$
$$
\label{1}
x = r \sin \theta \cos \phi . \tag{1}
$$
Sometimes they are given by their differential, applying differential $d$ to equation \ref{1} we get
$$
dx = -r \sin (\theta )   \sin (\phi ) d\phi+r  \cos (\theta ) \cos (\phi )d\theta +\sin (\theta )\cos (\phi ) dr .
$$
Now since by definition (using Einstein notation)
$$
dx = \frac{\partial x}{\partial \xi^i}d\xi^i,
$$
for $x = x(\xi^i)$,$\xi^i = (r,\theta,\phi)$ we should be able to recover the equation \ref{1} by
$$
 x=\int dx = \int \frac{\partial x}{\partial r}dr+ \int \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}d\theta +  \int \frac{\partial x}{\partial \phi}d\phi.
$$
But actually doing this I get
$$
x = 3 r \sin (\theta ) \cos (\phi ).
$$
Which differs from \ref{1} by a factor of $3$. Why is this?

Comment: Your integrals make no sense - what are these integrals *over*? What does $x = \int\mathrm{d}x$ actually mean? A differential n-form can be integrated - but over n-dimensional submanifolds, not by just writing an unspecified integral sign in front of it.

Comment: I definitely abused the notation to much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, the equation
$$
x = \int \frac{\partial x}{\partial r} dr + \int \frac{\partial x}{d\theta} d\theta + \int \frac{\partial x}{d\phi} d\phi
$$
doesn't make any sense. But even if we try to make sense of it, it's incorrect. You would expect each indefinite integral on the RHS to be equal to $x + C$ by the fundamental theorem of calculus, so we recover the equation
$$
x = 3x + C,
$$
which is the result you got. Note that you can replace $x$ here with any function $f : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$, and the same "reasoning" shows that $f = 3f + C$.

To correct this situation, note that you cannot take the indefinite integral of a differential form (in general, a differential form does not have an antiderivative), so we need to be explicit over what we're integrating over. By the fundamental theorem of line integrals, we have
$$
\int_\gamma dx = x(\gamma(1)) - x(\gamma(0)),
$$
where $\gamma : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}^3$ is any path. Let's consider a path $\gamma = (r, \theta, \phi)$ given in spherical coordinates. Then our computation becomes
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_\gamma \frac{\partial x}{\partial r}dr &=
\int_\gamma \sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)dr
= \int_0^1 \sin(\theta(t))\cos(\theta(t))r'(t)dt \\
\int_\gamma \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}d\theta &= \int_\gamma r\cos(\theta)\cos(\phi)d\theta = \int_0^1 r(t)\cos(\theta(t))\cos(\phi(t))\theta'(t)dt \\
\int_\gamma \frac{\partial x}{\partial \phi}\,d\phi &= -\int_\gamma r\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)d\phi = -\int_0^1 r(t)\sin(\theta(t))\cos(\phi(t))\phi'(t)dt,
\end{aligned}
$$
and we get
$$
\int_\gamma \frac{\partial x}{\partial r} dr + \int_\gamma \frac{\partial x}{d\theta} d\theta + \int_\gamma \frac{\partial x}{d\phi} d\phi
= \int_0^1 (x \circ \gamma)'(t)\,dt
= x(\gamma(1)) - x(\gamma(0))
= \int_\gamma dx,
$$
which is true.

Comment: I think the original in the question is the overloaded use of the symbol $x$, and unfortunately your completely correct answer has acquiesced to and followed that terrible notation. It would much improve if you labeled the equations and change the notation, say replace $dx$ with $d\mathbf x$  as in [Flanders] (https://archive.org/details/differentialform00flan/page/34/mode/2up)

Comment: @hyportnex Can you clarify how the symbol $x$ is overloaded? In my answer, $x$ is the coordinate function $\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$.